# Replace hard drive in Samsung NP900X1A - Need disassembly guidance

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I need to clone and restore existing 64GB HDD onto a 256GB HDD, can't manage to gain access to the internals of this laptop.

I checked with Samsung, they do not make manuals available nor will they help over the phone as to how to remove the bottom cover of this Samsung NP900X1A laptop.  They did offer to sell me a manual BUT they are out of stock for another 10-15 days.

I saw the screws under the 4 rubber feet and 4 rubber grommets, all removed but the cover is still on.  Does anyone know if there are more screws to take off here?

Also, I assume this replacement HDD will work (facto

Comment: There are often screws hiding under stickers, have you checked?

Comment: There may be screws under hatches. There may be plastic tangs whose release requires some part of the case to be pushed in a specific direction with some specific force. You may need to use a lever gently. If you are willing to break tangs that don't show externally, brute force will usually win. At a cost.

Answer (score 1):

There should only be a couple things you need to remove to get access to the HDD, it shouldn't require major disassembly. You may have to take the battery out and open any other panels on the bottom to get access to additional screws.  There always seem to be a lot of them hidden in odd locations like that.

As for the HDD itself fitting, you'll know once you get it apart.  It's pretty common for the laptop drive to have a normal SATA connection, making a drop in replacement pretty easy. There may be a drive caddy that you'll need to take the old drive out of and put the new one back into.

Comment: Yup, if it's a solid state drive, chances are very good a drop-in replacement will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any more screws. The cover should **slide** off once the screws are removed; push on the top edge. Use this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61ymoETm9PM) as reference.
[image: NP900X1A back]

The NP900X1A uses a mSATA SSD, shown boxed in red:
[image: NP900X1A inside]
A regular 2.5" laptop SATA HDD or SSD will **not** fit, and you will also need a special enclosure to access it outside of the laptop; otherwise you will need to use an intermediate drive to clone.